# Position Absolute в Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap4

Здесь на макете я вывел блок upline поверх parentline и прижал к верху через стиль css. Существует для этого встроенный метод в Bootstrap 4? Я не нашел к мурзилке.

```css
.upline {
    z-index: 1100;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px
}
.parentline {
    background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
    height: 200px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row dual">
                 <div class="col"></div>
                 <div class="col parentline">
                        <div class="row upline"></div>
                 </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Добавьте класс `sticky-top`

Comment: Нет, это не работает, сами проверьте
     <div class="col parentline">123
      <div class="sticky-top upline"></div>
     </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указывать [position-fixed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/)

```css
.upline {
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px
}
.parentline {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px
}
body {
    height: 2000px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row dual">
                 <div class="col"></div>
                 <div class="col parentline">
                        <div class="row upline position-fixed"></div>
                 </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает. Но с тем порядком, с которым у меня наполняется контент, у меня это окно спряталось за окном родителя. Пришлось оставить z-index в css. Вы не знаете случайно и этого решения в стиле Bootstrap? Выносить в отдельный вопрос уже как-то неловко. ) Документация в этом месте тоже скудна.

Comment: @GreenX5, не, думаю вариант с z-index подходящий. Не помню, что есть такое с z-index'ом, а гугление привело только к https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/approach/

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, да, оставлю z-index в css. Кажется разработчики устали, запутались в дебрях своих же переопределений и просто плюнули на всё под конец, это видно даже по наполнению финальных глав документации. ))